# How to specify the destination for an existing ClaimsIdentity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I'm using below code to create a ClaimIdentity in OpenIdConnectServerProvider.AuthorizationProvider. But the identity.Name is not searlized. How to allow the OpenIdConnectServer serarlize the name? Thanks.

The previous question is here [How to create a ClaimIdentity in asp.net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737757/how-to-create-a-claimidentity-in-asp-net-5)

```
var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
var factory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>>();
var identity = await factory.CreateAsync(user);                
context.Validated(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid leaking confidential data, `AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` refuses to serialize the claims that don't explicitly specify a destination.

To serialize the name (or any other claim), you can use the `.SetDestinations` extension:

```
var principal = await factory.CreateAsync(user);

var name = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);
if (name != null) {
    // Use "id_token" to serialize the claim in the identity token or "access_token"
    // to serialize it in the access token. You can also specify both destinations.
    name.SetDestinations(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                         OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
}

context.Validate(principal);
```

When adding a claim, you can also use the `AddClaim` extension taking a `destinations` parameter:

```
identity.AddClaim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Pinpoint",
     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
     OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
```

Comment: Updated to use the new syntax introduced by ASOS beta5.

Comment: This overload of `AddClaim` method no loner exists in v4.0.0 of `Openiddict.Abstractions`