# Asp.net core token based claims authentication with OpenIdConnect and angularjs: Bearer was forbidden

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

I'm using Asp.net core rc2 with OpenIdConnectServer. I'm using angular 1.x with augular-oauth2. After a few days, my error has digressed to

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:54275/api/Account/Username  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: Successfully validated the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Bearer.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: .
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Warning: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (Bearer).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
```

My ConfigureServices consists of

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("UsersOnly", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireClaim("role");
                });
            });
```

My configure has

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")), branch =>
            {
                branch.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
                {
                    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                    AutomaticChallenge = true,
                    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                    Audience = "http://localhost:54275/",
                    Authority = "http://localhost:54275/",
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "client1",
                        //ValidAudiences = new List<string> { "", "empty", "null"}
                    }
                });
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
            {
                options.AuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider();
                options.AccessTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
                options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
                options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token");
                options.LogoutEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/logout");
                options.RevocationEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/revoke");
                options.UseJwtTokens();
                //options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            });
```

My authorize attribute is defined on the Controller as

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UsersOnly", ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme), Route("api/Account")]
```

I store the token as a cookie and attach it to requests using an http interceptor in angular.

I generate the token with

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(GrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            // validate user credentials (demo mode)
            // should be stored securely (salted, hashed, iterated)
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionManager.GetDefaultConnectionString()))
            {
                if (!Hashing.ValidatePassword(context.Password, await con.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>("SELECT PassHash FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = @UserName", new { context.UserName })))
                {
                    context.Reject(
                        error: "bad_userpass",
                        description: "UserName/Password combination was invalid."
                        );
                    return;
                }

                // create identity
                var id = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationScheme);
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
                id.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

                // create metadata to pass on to refresh token provider
                var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"as:client_id", context.ClientId}
                });
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(id), props,
                    context.Options.AuthenticationScheme);
                ticket.SetAudiences("client1");
                //ticket.SetScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId, OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile, "api-resource-controller");
                context.Validate(ticket);
            }
        }
```

I've spent the last three days on this problem and I realize that at this point I'm probably missing something obvious due to lack of sleep. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which dotnet core assembly contains the extension method UseOpenIdConnectServer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you're seeing is likely caused by 2 factors:

- You're not attaching an explicit destination to your custom `role` claim so it will never be serialized in the access token. You can find more information about this security feature [on this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33806784/542757).
- `policy.RequireClaim("role");` might not work OTB, as IdentityModel uses an internal mapping that converts well-known JWT claims to their `ClaimTypes` equivalent: here, `role` will be likely replaced by `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` (`ClaimTypes.Role`). I'd recommend using `policy.RequireRole("user")` instead.

It's also worth noting that manually storing the `client_id` is not necessary as it's already done for you by the OpenID Connect server middleware.

You can retrieve it using `ticket.GetPresenters()`, that returns the list of authorized presenters (here, the client identifier). Note that it also automatically ensures a refresh token issued to a client A can't be used by a client B, so you don't have to do this check in your own code.