# Bearer was forbidden with Authorize filter in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4

While testing [IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) with [AspNetAuthorization](https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop)  tutorial I added the a simple `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` and since then I get this error:

> AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.

My user has this claim:
`new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator", ClaimValueTypes.String)`.

In `ConfigureServices` method:

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
        });

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                        .Build();

            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

and in `Configure` method:

```
   app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            ScopeName = "openid",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        });
```

**Debug output:**

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Executing action LearningEntityServer4.OAuth.ValuesController.Get (LearningEntityServer4.OAuth)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization was successful for user: myuser.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed for user: myuser.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Warning: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
```

What I missed in the configurations?

PS: I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771125/asp-net-core-token-based-claims-authentication-with-openidconnect-and-angularjs) SO post with no success.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the time to write up the internals of how role checks work in the claims world:

https://leastprivilege.com/2016/08/21/why-does-my-authorize-attribute-not-work/

In short - make sure the claim types you use for roles match the RoleClaimType on your ClaimsIdentity. Or replace `RequireRole` with `RequireClaim` in your policy and use the right types.

Comment: I appreciate you answer. One of the reasons that people can't use the well written IdS and specifically IdS4 is the lack of extensive examples and documentations to resolve their issues. I got stuck with this problem for days. Thanks for extensive explanation.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. In my case, I was testing things in Postman, but forgot to correctly request scopes and response_type to get a token with said information.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I fixed my problem before reading @leastprivilege detailed answer.

The problem was with the naming of the claim types,

I changed the following:

```
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator");
```

to this:

```
new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator");
```

and the authorization worked. That's because the underlying string values between these differ and my configuration was expecting the "role" one:

```
ClaimTypes.Role => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
JwtClaimTypes.Role => "role"
```

or one can do this based on his answer:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
        ScopeName = "scope",
        ScopeSecret = "secret",
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        RoleClaimType = "role"

    });
```

For detailed reasons behind it, read @leastprivilege answer

Answer (score 0):

Per the attached resource it appears that you should actually be placing the policy name in the authorize attribute like so `[Authorize("AdministratorOnly")]`.

https://damienbod.com/2016/02/14/authorization-policies-and-data-protection-with-identityserver4-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I applied that already via `[Authorize(Policy = "AdministratorOnly")]` and it didn't work.

Comment: @MohsenAfshin I notice that you don't have the issuer in the claim that you defined above `new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator", ClaimValueTypes.String, Issuer)`. Perhaps that is your issue? Based on the claim issued in the example https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetAuthorizationWorkshop#step-4-simple-policies

Comment: tried that and set the issuer, there seems to be a problem in config and I can't find it.